# Is there a tool that fills an area by its surrounding borders?

Tags: tools, fill

By example:

Is there a tool or a way to fill the white **X** shape so that the colors and patterns around it will blend into it as automatically as possible?

[image: http://snag.gy/PPOR2.jpg]

I.e., I want to remove the **X** as close to the picture as possible.

I'm working with GIMP, but I welcome answers in any software.

I know of the clone tool, but it's tedius. A pattern isn't good, since it needs to be adjusted by the colors and shades of the nearby pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Photoshop, the tool to do this is called Content-Aware:

[image: Content Aware]

To use it, I selected a box around the X, did a Fill (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), and selected `Content-Aware` from the Use dropdown.

A similar tool exists for GIMP, however I have never used it so your results may vary. Search for tutorials on the [Resynthesizer](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25219) tool.

Comment: check this post for an elaborate GIMP Resynthesizer tutorial: https://patdavid.net/2012/08/getting-around-in-gimp-heal-selection.html, download (for Windows) here: https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Resynthesizer-heal-selection-plugins-for-Windows